# How can I find the most upvoted comment(s) on a site?

Tags: support, comments, search

I saw one comment today that (deservedly so) was upvoted to +14 in a couple of hours.

Is there a way to find all the "good" - meaning highest-upvoted - comments on the entire site?

I'd strongly prefer an answer NOT involving mining the data dump; though of course if it's impossible in a regular web interface, the data dump query to do this would also be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, you can't just post a meta question without pics...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll have to use the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/new).  You can the Comment Score there, and do a sort on that value.  Link from the Comment's PostID to the question or answer that it's a comment *of*, and you're all set.

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102822) is the current highest-voted comment.  [Here's](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/76875/highest-voted-comments) my query.

And [here's](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/62344/top-25-comments-with-text) DavRob60's better query that directly links to the posts.

Comment: I prefer [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/62344/top-25-comments-with-text)

Comment: @DavRob60 Nice.  I whipped up mine in a few minutes, and didn't see the way to link to actual URLs.

Comment: updated to actually display user names : http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/62344/top-25-comments-with-text

Comment: [Here's one I wrote](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/338272/comments-with-highest-score?User=0) you can even filter by your **own** comments.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for a way to get all the top voted comments of a specific user on SFF,  I'd suggest [this query for Data Stack Exchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/577621/highest-voted-comments-for-a-user-on-sff).

Just enter the user Id and you are good to go. It will show you the comment, number of upvotes and the link to the post. As of now it returns only the top 250 comments but you can edit that yourself. For example, for me it shows:

[image]

To see top voted comments of whole SFF, see [Highest Voted comments on whole site](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/578503/highest-voted-comments-on-sff) even though it doesn't show display name of the person who posted the comment unlike the accepted answer.

#### The Top Three Comments

Following would be the top three comments on the site as of March 27th 2018:

1. ["*Let me know if this should be migrated to The Workplace*"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked) by [Hannover Fist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30947/hannover-fist).
2. ["*He makes sure that all his funds are in liquid assets.*"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174146/how-can-scrooge-mcduck-dive-into-money-without-hurting-himself) by [Mike Scott](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/23/mike-scott).
3. ["*Curious that in the wizarding world one doesn't need to include in their password at least a number, a special character, and a Parseltongue alphabet symbol*"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146641/why-would-snape-set-his-office-password-to-dumbledore) by [Federico Polani](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31736/federico-poloni).

Answer (score 4):

[**This pretty-printed StackExchange API query will show you those comments on Science Fiction SE.**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#order=desc&sort=votes&filter=!)Q2B_A2kjfNRDH5pUMXaRci3&site=scifi)  Follow the link, then submit the query with the "Run" button under the "Try It" heading.  (This requires Javascript enabled in your browser.)

The query will show an output that currently starts like this:

> ```
> {
>   "items": [
>     {
>       "owner": {
>         "user_id": 30947,
>         "display_name": "Hannover Fist",
>         "link": "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/30947/hannover-fist"
>       },
>       "score": 332,
>       "creation_date": 1442252581,
>       "post_id": 102822,
>       "comment_id": 237173,
>       "link": "https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked#comment237173_102822",
>       "body": "Let me know if this should be migrated to <b>The Workplace</b>."
>     },
> ```

The output shows the highest voted comments on the site, sorted in descending order by score.  The id, score, author and content of the comment are shown, as well as [a link to the comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked#comment237173_102822).  If you follow the link, you will find that the comment is on the question [Could I fake death to stop being Force-choked?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102822/4918)

If you want to find the highest voted comments on another SE site (possibly a Meta), then click on the "[edit]" link after the bold text "Science Fiction & Fantasy" right under the "Try It" heading, enter the name of the site into the input box that will appear in place of that label, then click on the site name from the list that drops down, then click on the Run button.

The StackExchange API is an alternate interface for StackExchange sites that is optimized for stability and automated access.  The pages in [the documentation for the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) that document individual methods in that API have a pretty-composer and pretty-printer form that lets you easily make queries to the API and print the results. The above link is a bookmark to such a pretty-printed query.

Comment: This is the correct answer, since DVK asked for a method **not** involving the data dump (which I take to mean the SEDE).

Comment: @SQB: It is now, but I'm not sure if this method was already possible in 2012-08 when OP asked the question.

Comment: Quite possibly. But it's not unheard of to change the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, bounties cannot be awarded on meta.